# Header refresh not working with jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, authentication, refresh, pageload

I'm updating my site to a more mobile friendly responsive design using jquerymobile.  Usually I have the user login and after checking the details are correct it will refresh them onto a new page.
However, I can't get this working with jquerymobile. Presumably this is because of the Ajax override features? Ajax is currently foreign to me :)
The abridged script is like below:

```
else
//else, all ok proceed with login
{
if(isset($_GET['redirect']))
{header ("Refresh: 0; URL=" . $_GET['redirect'] . "");}
else{header ("Refresh: 0; URL=cohome.php");
echo "Your login was successful, you are being redirected in one second <br />";
echo "(If your browser doesn't support this, <a href=\"cohome.php\">click here</a>)";}
}
```

many thanks

Actually, to simplify things. I have the same problem with my logout button.

```
<a href="logout.php">
```

which leads to

```
<?php
session_start();
// make double sure that logged out.
$_SESSION['logged'] = "0";
session_destroy();
header("Refresh: 0; URL=index.php");

echo "You have been logged out.<br />";
echo "You are being redirected to the homepage!<br />";
echo "(If your browser doesn't support this, <a href=\"index.php\">click here</a>)";
?>
```

Unfortunately, no redirect occurs.  It works fine on my standard site, only since starting to change over to jquery mobile.

Comment: edited for some more clarity hopefully

Answer (score 1):

Ah ok. It seems to work fine if I turn off ajax, using "data-ajax=false".

```
<form name="login" id="login" action="<?php echo "processCoLogin.php?".$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; ?>" data-ajax=false method="post">
```

or

```
<a href="logout.php" class="ui-btn" data-ajax=false>Log out</a>
```

But I'd prefer a solution where I didn't have to turn off ajax & could redirect using header(location) still.

Answer (score 0):

A header with a refresh of 0 makes not much sense. Consider using

```
header('location:' . $_GET['redirect']);
```

instead. Or, if you wish to display the redirect message, increase the refresh time. Last, but not least, you could also echo a refresh:

```
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='3; url=" . $_GET['redirect']) . "'>";
```

However, using meta-refresh is not recommended. But if you are using JS and rely on it, you could also use a JS redirection:

```
echo "setTimeout(\"location.href = '" . $_GET['redirect']) . "';\", 3000);";
```

There are several ways, but a PHP refresh with 0 seconds isn't the best idea in my opinion.

Comment: The header refresh set to zero was just to whisk the user through, unless they were on a very bad connection etc.  Increasing the refresh time to 1 didn't make any difference.  Trying header('location' isn't working either). I'm  going to have to strip this back and see where its going wrong.